# Pointing to an item not in the list in C

Tags: c, list, dynamic, data-structures

I have a list that holds the values: 25, 30, 45, 60, 65, 80, 90

I was curious what happens if I implement the expression ptr2->next->next, considering ptr2 is pointing to the value 80. Since this expression is pointing to the value that would be after 90, should I expect to receive 0 or an error code?

Comment: Why don't you just it yourself and find out?

Answer (score 0):

`ptr2->next->next` is a pointer, not a value, which will point to either `NULL` (in case you construct the nodes this way), or to some junk. In both cases, trying to dereference it results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The last element in a linked list should have `next = NULL`; that's how you indicate that it's the end of the list. So `ptr2->next->next` will return `NULL`, which is `0`.

If you then try to deference that, e.g. `ptr2->next->next->next`, you will be invoking Undefined Behavior. On most systems this will produce an application crash, such as a `Segmentation Violation` on Linux. But this is not guaranteed by the C specification; anything can happen when you try to dereference a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is a regular (singular) list then `ptr2->next->next` would point to `NULL`.